# What is a proper method to make Dua

Tags: dua

Can anyone tell me what is the method of making Dua some people say there is a proper method to make Dua because I just make Dua by starting with durood and ask Allah what I want and end it with durood so what is a proper way my another question is can  one call upon Allah directly without any method or a specific way

Answer (score 1):

### Halal income and giving everyone what they deserve

*امام صادق عليه السلام:
 إِذَا أَرَادَ أَحَدُكُمْ أَنْ يُسْتَجَابَ لَهُ فَلْيُطَيِّبْ كَسْبَهُ وَ لْيَخْرُجْ مِنْ مَظَالِمِ النَّاسِ وَ إِنَّ اللَّهَ لَا يُرْفَعُ إِلَيْهِ دُعَاءُ عَبْدٍ وَ فِي بَطْنِهِ حَرَامٌ أَوْ عِنْدَهُ مَظْلِمَةٌ لِأَحَدٍ مِنْ خَلْقِهِ.*

Imam Sadiq: If a person wants his dua/prayer to be answered, then he his earnings must be *halal* and give people what they deserve. The prayer of a person who has haram money in his belly or one who hasn't  fulfilled the rights of another, will not ascend to Allah

### Timing

*قالَ الاْمامُ علي - عَلَيْهِ السلام - : إغْتَنِمُوا الدُّعاءَ عِنْدَ خَمْسَةِ مَواطِنَ: عِنْدَ قِرائَةِ الْقُرْآنِ، وَ عِنْدَ الاْذانِ، وَ عِنْدَ نُزُولِ الْغَيْثِ، وَ عِنْدَ الْتِقاءِ الصَفَّيْنِ لِلشَّهادَةِ، وَ عِنْدَ دَعْوَةِ الْمَظْلُومِ، فَاِنَّهُ لَيْسَ لَها حِجابٌ دوُنَ الْعَرْشِ.
«بحارالأنوار، ج 90، ص 343، ح 1»*

Imam Ali said: Hold dear 5 moments for prayers:

- When Quran is being read
- At the time of Adhan
- At the time of rain
- At the time of war and jihad - that is done for the path of Allah
- At the time of oppression and crying of an oppressed.

At these moments there are no barriers for praying.

Close to Azan/iftar or speical eids always increases the chance of dua.

### Place

Holy places like the Kaaba or Masjid al Haram or other holy lands increase chance of your dua getting answered.

### Purity

Having wudu is great.

### Good deeds

*حضرت محمد صلی الله علیه و آله :
مَنْ أَرادَ تُسْتَجابُ دَعْوَتُهُ وَ أَنْ تُكْشَفَ كُرْبَتُهُ فَلْيُفَرِّجْ عَنْ مُعْسِرٍ؛*

Prophet Muhammad(PBUH): Anyone who wants his prayer to be answered and his sorrow to disappear should give time (be lenient) to one in need.

*امام علی علیه السلام :
لَا تَسْتَبْطِئْ إِجَابَةَ دُعَائِكَ وَ قَدْ سَدَدْتَ طَرِيقَهُ بِالذُّنُوب‏*

Imam Ali: Don't think your dua will be answered late — when [it's that] you've closed the doors for it to be answered by your sins.

Prophet Muhammad (PBUH): Sending your greetings to me, will answer your calls and is the alms of your deeds.

### Dua's content:

*امام موسی کاظم علیه السلام :
أوشَک دَعوَةً‌ وَ أسرَعُ إجابَةُ دُعاءُ المَرءِ لاِخیهِ‌ بِظَهرِ الغَیبِ؛*

Imam Musa Kadhim: a prayer that is more likely to happen is the dua that is done for your brother in faith in his absence

### How to begin

*حضرت محمد صلی الله علیه و آله :
لا يُرَدُّ دُعاءٌ أَوَّلُهُ بِسْمِ اللّهِ الرَّحمنِ الرَّحيمِ*

Prophet Muhammad(PBUH):  A prayer that is began with بِسْمِ اللّهِ الرَّحمنِ الرَّحيمِ is not rejected

*امام صادق*
*تبدا فتحمد الله و تذکر نعمه عندک ثم تشکره ثم تصلی علی النبی و آله ثم تذکر ذنوبک فتقر بها ثم تستعیذ منها ، فهذا جهة الدعاء*

in the beginning of dua:

- praise Allah
- and remember his bounties upon you
- then thank him
- then send greetings to Prophet Muhammad and his family
- then remember your sins and admit [to your doings]
- and seek refuge in Allah.

This is how dua is to be done

Having a sense of humility and being desperate:

*أَمَّن یجُِیبُ الْمُضْطَرَّ إِذَا دَعَاهُ وَ یَكْشِفُ السُّوءَ (62- نمل)*

Is He [not best] who responds to the desperate one when he calls upon Him?

Similar to how we mention our own sins and belittle ourselves, we should have absolute faith in Allah and see him above and beyond us.